# Read Violation when Accessing 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, access-violation

I got a really weird read violation error when I try to access the addresses that are supposed to be inside a 2D array. 
Please read several lines of my code:

```
Class class : public SuperClass
{ 
public:
    bool checkDirt(int x, int y)
    {
        if(DirtField[x][y] != nullptr) //read violation error given here
................

private:
    Dirt* DirtField[64][60];
}
```

The DirtField 2D array consist of pointers to Dirt objects and nullptrs

When I tried to debug the program, it tells me the x and y are always well with in the bound of the 2D array, say x=21, y=14. But no matter what value is x and y I always get the error.

Please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If `DirtField` is a null pointer, then `DirtField[x][y]` would have to dereference it to check if `DirtField[x][y]` is a null pointer. Compare `DirtField` and/or `DirtField[x]` to nullptr first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that the debugger gives the correct place of the access violation and let's proceed by elimination:

- `DirtField` is a fixed 64x60 array. So `DirtField` can't be nullptr, and the read access error can't come from allocation of `DirtField`.
- if you have checked that `x` and `y` are both within range, the read access error can't come from an out of bound access to the array either.
- `DirtFiled[x][y]` contains a pointer to `Dirt` that you compare with anothers pointer without derefencing any of them.  So it couldn't be an issue with the `Dirt` class either, or the content of the `DirtField` array.

The only problem left, would be that the object on which you've called `checkDirt()` is itself invalid.  Something like:

```
Class *myobject;  // unitinialized pointer 
myobject->checkDirt(21,14);
```